# Get NSView screen rect and display ID

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsview, nsrect

Given an `NSView`, how can I get its screen-rect and the display it's on, so I can use [`CGDisplayCreateImageForRect`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/Quartz_Services_Ref/Reference/reference.html)?

I found the NSWindow [`convertRectToScreen`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWindow_Class/Reference/Reference.html) method, but it's only available from 10.7 (I need 10.6 as well), and it still doesn't give the display the `NSView` is on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you don't care about getting the actual pixel size of the view (because it'd differ between HDPI and regular displays -- I can't imagine it'd be a useful value right now), you basically just want to use a combination of NSView's `convertRect:toView:` and NSWindow's `convertBaseToScreen:`. So, for example, `[someView.window convertBaseToScreen:[someView convertRect:someView.bounds toView:nil]]`. This is assuming you aren't transforming the view in any unusual-ish sort of ways (rotating it or something). Bear in mind that you should still add a check for whether the window responds to `convertRectToScreen:` and use that if it does -- that way you avoid using the deprecated method (`convertBaseToScreen:`) where possible.

Afterward, if you need the exact pixel size for the screen, you'd use NSScreen's `convertRectToBacking:` (I'm not sure if you'll need it for this). As for determining the screen, NSWindow has its `screen` method, which should be sufficient in most cases. The only issue I can see is when the view crosses screens, so you may have to check if it's intersecting any other displays and merge images and so on. That said, I'm not sure if `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect` will account for this or not. You'll have to test that yourself.

Comment: The point of this question was to find a way *not* using `convertRectToScreen`, which is only available from 10.7 on...

Comment: Should be fixed (uses `convertBaseToScreen:` now). It's deprecated though, so it's probably worthwhile to add a check for whether the window responds to `convertRectToScreen:` and use that when it does.

Comment: Yea but `convertBaseToScreen:` takes a point, not a rect. Do you think something like this is correct : https://gist.github.com/3581098?

Comment: I tested it and the results are the same, though you'd have an easier time just doing `view_rect.origin = [window convertBaseToScreen:view_rect.origin]`.

Comment: Right, thanks. There is one more problem though, it seems that the coordinate system of the screen/window are flipped?! So basically Apple is not consistent with itself. The problem is that with your method everything works, but when I look at the image generated by `CGDisplayCreateImageForRect`, it takes a shot of the wrong part of the screen; it's as if the y axis was flipped. If I try to take a screenshot of the bottom of the screen, it shows me a screenshot of the top etc. The x axis seems fine. Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: And thanks for your help, gave you a +1, will accept if the above issue can be resolved...

Comment: That's really a separate question, though it's fairly simple to fix (flip the coordinates yourself).

Comment: I guess. I was just worried that that might've been considered a hack, since there's no way to know it won't change in the future, but I'll guess I'll just flip it manually then. Thanks again